# Ajustar contenido dentro de una figura

Tags: html, css

Tengo dificultad para ajustar el contenido dentro de una etiqueta `<figure>` que debe tener una altura fija en este caso de 250px. El problema es que dentro de esta figura tengo un div y párrafo. Lo que quisiera es que por mas `<br>` que agregue no sobrepase la altura de la figura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si intento poner la altura en "auto" ya no respetaría la altura fija de 250px.

Tengo la demo reproduciendo el problema: [DemoStackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-e3fug2?file=index.html)

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.content figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #3b444b;
}
.item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #29323c 0%, #485563 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.item h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item p {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <figure>
          <div class="item">
            <h2>Demo</h2>
            <p>
              <br /><br />
              <br /><br />
              <br /><br />
            </p>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Quisiera que quedara de esta manera sin importar cuantos `<br>` se agregue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregándole simplemente un `height: 65%;` al class `.item`, se ve como estabas buscando:

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.content figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #3b444b;
}
.item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #29323c 0%, #485563 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.item h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item p {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5%;
  position: relative;
  height: 65%; 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <figure>
          <div class="item">
            <h2>Demo</h2>
            <p>
              <br /><br />
              <br /><br />
              <br /><br />
            </p>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Al definir el `height` fijo de un `div` evitas que este se defina automáticamente en base a su contenido, en este caso los `br`.

Eso se va a respetar aunque su contenido intente exceder su altura definida.